# How can I run (execute) many files with the same filename wild card using one command?

Tags: aws, execute-command, wildcards

I am using a desktop Windows program that copies multiple Linux ASCII text job files to an AWS CloudFormation (EC2, Linux), as well as copies data to sub-folders.

All of the ASCII text "job files" contain two lines like:

```
cd folder1
~/myexecutable --config conf.txt --otherdata ~/MainDataFolder/data.abct --out data_out.abc
```

All of the job files have the same wild card "myjob" in their filename, like:

```
myjob1
myjob2
myjob3
```

Is there a **single** Linux command that will execute all the job files with the same wild card in their filename?

Something maybe like:

```
exec myjob*
```

Comment: I was able to use `sh ./myjob*` but it only ran one file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xargs` command like this:

```
echo ./myjob* | xargs -n 1 sh
```

Here, `echo` will list all the filenames matching the wildcard `myjob*` to standard output. The command `xargs` will get each *word* from standard input and run for each one (the parameter `-n 1` means "Use at most **1 argument per command line**") the command `sh` like this:

```
sh ./myjob1
sh ./myjob2
sh ./myjob3
```

--

An alternative, but essentially similar command would be:

```
xargs -n 1 sh <<<$(echo ./myjob*)
```